# How to set a 3D scatter plot to black and white in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a binary 3D array that I want to display as a scatter plot in MATLAB, but the default yellow and blue color scheme is atrocious and a black and white plot would suit my purposes much better. However, calling a color in the scatter3() command causes all the points to be that color, and I would like to follow the traditional scheme (0 is black, 1 is white)

I generate the scatter plot simply, like so:

```
[x,y,z] = meshgrid(1:100,1:100,1:100);
scatter3(x(:),y(:),z(:),5,array(:),'filled')
```

As a followup question, are there better ways to display a 3D array (in this case, my array is a stack of images)? Or is a scatter plot generally sufficient?

Comment: After creating figure use `colormap('gray')` to change to grayscale colormap. See [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/overview-of-volume-visualization.html#f5-5598) for a discussion on visualizing 3D volumes.

Comment: Delightfully simple. Thanks for the pointer!